# vb.net programming a button press on a website

Tags: html, vb.net, internet-explorer-11

I am working with Visual Studio Express 2013 and trying to program some code to press a button on the web page.  I have read many examples and gotten similar examples but none seem to be working on mine.  Below is the code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer


IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate("http://www.timeanddate.com/date/weekdayadd.html")

Do Until IE.ReadyState = SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop


Dim elementcol As Object
elementcol = IE.Document.getelementsbyclassname("bigger")

elementcol.invokemember("click")




End Sub
```

This is from many examples but none of it seems to work.  Could anyone provide me with some feedback.  I am referencing shdocvw.dll, HTML Dialogs 1.0 Type Library, Microsoft HTML Object Library, and Microsoft Internet Controls.

It makes it to the final line and breaks.

Could I get ideas from anyone why this isn't working?

Thanks so much for your feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

Which button are you trying to click? the bigger class only refers to the set to today link. for this you would be better off getting a collection of HTML A elements, checking its innerHTML for "Today" then invoking the click

like so

```
        Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
        IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate("http://www.timeanddate.com/date/weekdayadd.html")

        Do Until IE.ReadyState = SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        Dim elementcol As Object
        elementcol = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("A")
        For Each f In elementcol
            If f.InnerHtml = "Today" Then
                f.click()
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: I appreciate the response but when I go into Visual Express 2013 it doesn't give me the option for the getelementsbytagname, am I missing a reference library?

I am beginning to wonder if I have the appropriate Visual Express because a lot of peoples advice doesn't seem to work on Visual Express 2013

Comment: I used 2010. The only reference was Microsoft Internet control. Does the code error when run? I didn't have the option in the IDE but it still ran fine